# How to get ConfirmIntent to work on Amazon Lex and Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-lex

I am trying to develop an IT chat bot to help people answer issues that they could fix on their own if they only had the correct information or steps. I am using Amazon Lex as the bots infrastructure. I have written the intents in the Lex console, and lambda functions for each intent to validate and fulfill the intent. The issue I am running into is using confirmIntent in lambda. With  confirmintent I want the user to be prompted with "Did this resolve your issue?" after the bot prints the steps and then based on if the user says Yes or No the bot responds. The issue I am running into is when I set it up like AWS documentation says to I get this error:

`[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type function is not JSON serializable Traceback (most recent call last):`

I am not sure what the error means and was needing some help to figure it out to fix my lambda functions so that the function works correctly.
below is the basic format of my code with just one intent for example

````
def get_slots(intent_request):
    return intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']

def rreplace(s, old, new, occurrence):
    li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
    return new.join(li)

def elicit_slot(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, slot_to_elicit, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ElicitSlot',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'slotToElicit': slot_to_elicit,
            'message': message
        }
    }

def close(session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }
    }

    return response

def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    print("This is sessionAttributes value in delegate", session_attributes)
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }

def parse_int(n):
    try:
        return int(n)
    except ValueError:
        return float('nan')

def build_validation_result(is_valid, violated_slot, message_content):
    print("Inside build validation function")
    if message_content is None:
        print("inside if statment in validation function above first return")
        return {
            "isValid": is_valid,
            "violatedSlot": violated_slot,
        }
        print("inside if statment in validation function above second return")

    return {
        'isValid': is_valid,
        'violatedSlot': violated_slot,
        'message': {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': message_content}
    }

def confirm_intent(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, message):
    print('Made it inside confirm_intent')
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ConfirmIntent',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'message': {
                'contentType': 'PlainText',
                'content': "test"
            }
        }
    }

def password(intent_request):
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']
    output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
    slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    # whatever you want to do
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        slot = get_slots(intent_request)
        passwordType = validate_intro_request(slots)
        if not passwordType['isValid']:
            slot[passwordType['violatedSlot']] = None
            
            return elicit_slot(intent_request['sessionAttributes'],
                               intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                               slot,
                               passwordType['violatedSlot'],
                               passwordType['message'])
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, slots)

    if source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        # action fulfillment code
        msg = "did that resolve the issue"
        return confirm_intent(output_session_attributes, 'PasswordReset', slots, msg)
        
def validate_password_request(password):
    issues = ['need to reset my password']
    if password is not None and password.lower() not in issues:
        return build_validation_result(False,'password','We do not understand your {}, please try to reword your issue for password information'.format(passwords))

def dispatch(intent_request):
    logger.debug('dispatch userId={}, intentName={}'.format(intent_request['userId'], intent_request['currentIntent']['name']))
    

    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']

    # Dispatch to your bot's intent handlers
    if intent_name == 'PasswordReset':
        return i_password(intent_request)
    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    Route the incoming request based on intent.
    The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
    """
    # By default, treat the user request as coming from the Pacific timezone.
    os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Los_Angeles'
    time.tzset()
    logger.info('Received event: {}'.format(event))

    return dispatch(event)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the below line is incorrect as the message is an object of content type and content. You're passing only string it should map to contents.

This may cause the Jain parser error at lex,

```
msg = "did that resolve the issue"
        return confirm_intent(output_session_attributes, 'PasswordReset', slots, msg)
```

`msg` variable should map to content property of message in confirm intent function.

Hope this resolves your issues.